# Python. AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'types'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
import telebot
import send_message

def help_menu(data):
    mark = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    b1_1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='key 1 - 1', callback_data='1-1')
    b1_2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='key 1 - 2', callback_data='1-2')
    b1_3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='key 1 - 3', callback_data='1-3')
    b1_4 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='key 1 - 4', callback_data='1-4')
    mark.add(b1_1, b1_2, b1_3, b1_4)
    send_message.send_menu(data['message']['from']['id'], 'НАЖМИ', mark)
```

Бот спокойно авторизуется, принимает запросы и отвечает на них. Пытаюсь добавить кнопки, но не получается.
Вылетает ошибка AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'types'
Хотя сам VS Code пишет, что есть такое
[image: 123]

уже переустанавливал библиотеки и все равно не помогло

Comment: from telebot import * 
пробовали?
Где запускается бот? Что с доступами к папкам? Всё есть? Интерпретатор для запуска используется какой? С доступом к установленным пакетам?

Comment: from telebot import * сделал - NameError: name 'telebot' is not defined
запускается у себя на машине, VS Code
про доступ к папкам не знаю, должно все работать, ведь он принимает и отправляет запросы
объясните подробнее про доступы к папкам и пакетам

Comment: Мне кажется, что в ВС коде используется один интерпретатор, который знает путь к установленным пакетам, а при запуске используется другой интерпретатор, который пути туда не имеет. Либо пакет, либо интерпретатор установлены неверно. Я бы начал с того, что попытался явно прописать используемый интерпретатор. Первым дело "which python3.х", а потом в запускаемом прописал бы его явно в файле "#!interpreter_path" в самом верху.

Comment: @DamienDamieAmfiet, тогда бы интерпретатор ругался на отсутствие модуля `telebot`, да и у автора винда, а там шебанг строка не имеет эффекта :)

Comment: @Blubber00, файл вашего скрипта случаем не `telebot.py`? Если да, то переименуйте

Comment: @DamienDamieAmfiet переустановил и интерпретатор, не помогает. Что за дичь...

Comment: @gil9reg, файла с таким названием нет у меня

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `telebot` и `pyTelegramBotApi` - это разные библиотеки, но обе они импортируются через `import telebot`.
Вам нужно выполнить следующее:

```py
pip unistall telebot
pip uninstall pyTelegramBotApi
pip install pyTelegramBotApi
```